# binary value comes wrong after & with 0x000000FF

Tags: java, netbeans, byte

In the code below which is part of a tutorial found, i thought that ater running it the expected result of byte0 would be the same value as of int, 190:

```
int i = 190;
byte byte0 = (byte)((i & 0x000000FF));
```

Though, the result given by Netbeans is -66. Any ideas why?

Comment: Because Java doesn't have unsigned bytes (or unsigned anything, unless you count char).

Comment: You are doing the same thing as `(byte) 190` which is `-66`  The mask isn't doing anything.

Comment: By comparison you can do `byte b = (byte) i;` and `int j = b & 0xFF; // == 190`